# Create react app App fails when importing custom library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

I created a brand new app using creat-react-app. got it running. My company has a custom library of components in an npm repository.

I pull that in, and import one of the components. I get a failure immediately.

The error I'm getting is:

> ./node_modules/*the module in question*/index.js
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)

When I look at the index.js file of this node module, the only line there is:

```
export * from './src';
```

The ./src/index.js file exports all the components individually.

It's clear this is choking webpack or something. I haven't really seen things exported like this.

Comment: it means re-export all named exports from `./src`. I'm not sure if webpack can handle it.